# PNG logo shown twice and disorted in splashscreen on Android 5 (api v22)

Tags: android, react-native, android-layout, splash-screen

I'm working on splashscreen for android app build with react native. Splashscreen consist of solid color background and logo in PNG format. Splashscreen is working fine on new android versions but on android 5 (api version 22) logo is shown twice, once correctly and once distorted (stretched on entire screen). See screenshot at the end.

Splashscreen is setup with npm package `react-native-splash-screen` and it's source code looks like this:

*res/layout/launch_screen.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splashscreen"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

and drawable/splashscreen looks like this:

*res/drawable/splashscreen.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/purple"/>
    <item
        android:width="257dp"
        android:height="33dp"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/logo"
        android:gravity="center" />
</layer-list>
```

I have tried almost all different combination of `android:gravity`, `android:scaleType` and `android:tileMode` with no success. Even when I move the logo to `<bitmap>` tag in the item it was still the same. I did found out that when I change the gravity prop to some different value then the distorted logo move accordingly. But I can't get rid of it. Also I do not understand why is the logo visible twice if there is defined only once.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

[image: bad splashscreen]

Comment: Why not place a `ImageView` inside your `LinearLayout`? Set the `LinearLayout` background to `@color/purple` and the `ImageView` background to `@mipmap/logo`.

Comment: Thanks @HB. This actually works. Can you submit it as a normal response to the question so I can mark it as a correct answer?

Comment: Please see my answer provided below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place an `ImageView` inside your `LinearLayout`, then set the `LinearLayout` background to `@color/purple` and the `ImageView` background to `@mipmap/logo`, as shown below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/purple">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@mipmap/logo"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```